# Disk types for DVD-RAM

Tags: dvd-burning

I just bought a new computer and it has a DVD-RAM drive. I am trying to re-install OS on that machine but failing to do so because the only DVDs I have now are DVD+R which DVD-RAM is failing to read.

What type of DVDs can DVD-RAM read? My OLD machine where I am burning DVD has the following:

1 DVD±RW/RAM and 1 BD-ROM/HD DVD-ROM

Thanks for your help!

Comment: The new machines has: 1 DVD±RW/RAM

Comment: Are you sure it's dvd-ram?  That was a short lived and unpopular technology that existed years ago before dvd+/-rw came about, and required the use of special cartridges rather than conventional media that could be loaded in a slot or tray.

Comment: Oh, lots of new drives support it without the cartridges. Most of my newer drives are labelled as such

Comment: I have one from.. 8 years ago? It claims DVD-RAM support. The drives are more or less ubiquitus now, it's finding a DVD-RAM disc that's hard. They're often labelled [DVD Multi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DVD_Multi).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the SATA cable was connected to the 6GB port so I moved it to the 3GB port and it is able to read the DVD+R dvds. I didnt think it would matter... Thanks to @Bob and @Journeyman's leading me to the right direction!

Answer (score 1):

DVD ram drives (or any reasonably modern DVD drives) should have no issues with DVD+ DVD- or any other common disk types - if you had an early DVD reader  you'd have issues- and *all* dvd ram disk capable drives are new enough to support most common disk types. Your problem is likely somewhere else.

Comment: You are right. The drive can't seem to read any dvds at all. I have tried reading a dvd that comes with shrink-wrap softwares and it wasn't able to read the dvd (I was able to read the dvd just fine from my old desktop and a laptop). How can I go about diagnosing the issue?

Comment: *all dvd ram disk capable drives are new enough **not** to support most common disk types* Typo?

Comment: @Emon Check the SATA & power connectors, try unplugging and replugging it. Maybe try a different SATA port or different SATA cable. My DVD drive on a new computer would randomly fail (disconnect) until I got the cable replaced.

Comment: "Can't read any DVDs at all" - It could be the drive - does it do CDs? Considering things, the best option is to use a known good drive to install the os - I favour USB sticks ;). @bob - corrected, thanks.

Comment: Bob, looks like the SATA cable was connected to the 6GB port so I moved it to the 3GB port and it is able to read the DVD+R dvds. I didnt think it would matter... Thanks you all for your input!

Comment: One of you should post that as an answer, and select it as thr right one! The issue is solved, and it'll make sure others with the same issue can find it as an answer, and the question wouldn't get bumped up periodically